How to handle projects
I try to use neovim-project and session-manager plugins but dont really know how to save/load a project.  Running
:Telescope neovim-project history

I have no result.  When running
:NeovimProjectLoadHist [path to my project]


I have project not found

Even if a use SessionSave nothing works.  I think I miss some understanding about how to ..
In my config of neovim-project I put some paths to my projects but nothing change.
If someone can give me the steps to use these plugins.
Thk
Tried to configure, searching on the web without results.  Expect to manage projects inside Neovim.
